# Adding a link to view email with images in HTML

Tags: html, email

I've been asked to add a link inside of an HTML email template that when clicked, displays any blocked images in the email. I've looked all over and cannot find any information on how this is accomplished.

Basically, there would be a link: "View this email with images"

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If the email client blocks images, it will usually add a `Show external images` button.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a website that displays the same content as the email, then make a link pointing to that page.

There's nothing special about it.

Comment: But, will that display in the email then or direct them to a new page?

Comment: @user699242: No; it'll be a normal link.  It is not possible to display it in the email.

Comment: Okay, so it is not possible to have a link in the email that will take the place of your email clients "display image link"?

Comment: No; you cannot interact with the email client.